# Array bounds error with CryptoStream.Read

Tags: c#, stream, cryptography, buffer, cryptostream

I have a server/client system, which encrypts images on the server (python) and decrypts them on the client (c#). The cryptography part is working perfectly, except for trying to decrypt info which is several-blocks long (for example, an image, and not a "Hello World" string).

So, when I try to decrypt encrypted images via a CryptoStream -
sometimes it works, and for some reason - sometimes it doesn't.

This is the decryption process of the image:

```
public static byte[] DecryptBytesFromBytes(byte[] encryptedImage, byte[] key)
        {
            byte[] decryptedImage;

            // Create an Aes object with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = key;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                byte[] IV = new byte[16];
                byte[] cipherBytes = new byte[encryptedImage.Length - IV.Length];

                Array.Copy(encryptedImage, IV, IV.Length);
                Array.Copy(encryptedImage, IV.Length, cipherBytes , 0, cipherBytes.Length);

                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                using (var input = new MemoryStream(cipherBytes))
                using (var output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(input, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        var buffer = new byte[1024];
                        var read = cryptStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        while (read > 0)
                        {
                            output.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                            read = cryptStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Error here
                        }
                        decryptedImage= output.ToArray();
                    }
                }
                return decryptedImage;
            }
```

If it helps, I get the same error even when doing:

```
cryptStream.CopyTo(output);
```

This is the python code for encryption:

```
@staticmethod
def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

def encrypt(self, message):
    message = self.pad(message)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(str.encode(self.key), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)
```

### The Exception

Sometimes I get this error: `System.ArgumentException: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`

The full stacktrace:

```
at System.Buffer.BlockCopy (System.Array src, System.Int32 srcOffset, System.Array dst, System.Int32 dstOffset, System.Int32 count) [0x00097] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.InternalTransformBlock (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount, System.Byte[] outputBuffer, System.Int32 outputOffset) [0x000b0] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalDecrypt (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) [0x00020] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.TransformFinalBlock (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) [0x0002e] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x002e3] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Project.Crypto.DecryptBytesFromBytes (System.Byte[] encryptedImage, System.Byte[] key) [0x000b9] in C:\Users\user\Desktop\Project\Crypto.cs:129
```

Note that `Project.Crypto.DecryptBytesFromBytes` is the decryption function.

Does anybody have any idea why it happens, and how can I fix it? Let me know if more information is needed.

This is what I found in the documentation of the function `Read()`:

```
// Exceptions:
//   T:System.ArgumentException:
//     Thesum of the count and offset parameters is longer than the length of the buffer.
```

By the way, I use CBC mode and padding of zeros.

I would like to clarify one last thing - I do this whole process just so I could take encrypted bytes, and turn them into decrypted bytes. If there is another way to decrypt bytes into bytes in c#, please let me know.

Comment: Do you `.FlushFinalBlock()` when you encrypt the file?

Comment: Nope. It is a bit complicated to explain, but the files are encrypted with python (on a server). What does `FlushFinalBlock()` when encrypting? @JQSOFT

Comment: I see. You should do then. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.flushfinalblock?view=netcore-3.1)...

Comment: Could you give me further information? Where should I do it? what does it actually do? @JQSOFT

Comment: The last line. Just before closing and disposing the stream or the last line in the `using {..}` block if you are using it.

Comment: @JQSOFT but the error occures before the last line. Is it ok?

Comment: Anyways, I get `System.NotSupportedException: FlushFinalBlock() method was called twice on a CryptoStream. It can only be called once.`

Comment: Excuse me, but are you talking about the encryption process? Because again, I use python for encryption.

Comment: The last line in the _Encryption_ routine buddy.  You need to fill the missing length. If you don't write it correctly then you won't read it.

Comment: PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you for the help. @JQSOFT if you are talking about padding empty space, I actually do it with null bytes "\0".

Comment: @JQSOFT using C# for the decryption. Sorry for the confusion. I'd like to remind, again, that sometimes the decryption works, and sometimes it doesn't - the description of the exception seems like something very trivial, but I can't manage to get around it.

Comment: @JQSOFT may be right about this: it might be impossible to debug this *without* seeing the encryption code also.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk my bad, updated. Thank you for the help.

Comment: And that's using pycryptodome?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It uses a module called `Crypto`, which I think is a different name for pycryptodome. Not sure tho.

Comment: It could be either pycrypto or pycryptodome. pycrypto is no longer maintained, pycryptodome is a fork of pycrypto that is well maintained.

Comment: I don't see how that exception is possible for that code. Is this really the actual code that is throwing the exception?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yep. It doesn't make sense. According to the exception's description, buffer.Length + 0 is bigger than buffer.Length ...

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk In my opinion, there is a problem with the null ("/0") padding. Seems like sometimes it can't be read. Do u have any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Please print out the full stacktrace. If I'd had to guess either you're not receiving the full ciphertext **or** the Python code only pads with zeros if required and C# expects the zero padding to be present even if the end of the plaintext is already on a block boundary. But without enough code that's just guessing; we cannot debug with the amount of code provided.

Comment: Almost forgot: zero padding is non-deterministic if the plaintext might end with zero bytes. Furthermore, using just CBC over a network connection is criminally insecure. You should use transport security (i.e. TLS).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thank you for your help. Could you explain please about the consequences of using CBC only? By the way, I updated the question - added some more code to the c# section and added the full stacktrace. Thanks a lot!